# Add information Mysql

Tags: php, html

This says I have an error on Line 15.

I'm hoping to add information and then for it to appear in a table. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjSc5.png)

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in N:\ftp\compc\ac12mm\untitled folder\addContact.php on line 15

Comment: Don't post images when text will suffice. A picture may paint a thousand words, but a dead link will paint your question unanswerable.

Comment: How do I paste the code? It isnt allowing me. Please help

Comment: Can you post your error please ? saying you have an error on one line is pretty vague

Comment: It's probably not allowing you because you have not enough text. Add details about the error and you might pass the threshold for text/code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this way :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (id,name, ...) VALUES (0,'name', ..) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to close your `$db->prepare` function.

Replace this(line 15):

```
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("insert into stock values (
     null, :game, :console, :age, :genre,:price, :status, :stock, :purchased,
     :low, :date, :picture,)";
```

With this:

```
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("insert into stock values (
         null, :game, :console, :age, :genre,:price, :status, :stock, :purchased,
         :low, :date, :picture)");
```

**Also:**

Replace this(line 16):

```
$dbParams = array('game'=> $newstockgame, 'console'=> $newstockconsole,
'age'=> $newstockage, 'genre'=> $newstockgenre, 'status'=> $newstockstatus, 
'purchased'=> $newstocklow, 'date'=> $newstockdate, 'picture'=> $newstockpicture);
```

With this:

```
$dbParams = array('game'=> $newstockgame, 'console'=> $newstockconsole, 
'age'=> $newstockage, 'genre'=> $newstockgenre, 'price'=> $newstockprice, 
'status'=> $newstockstatus, 'stock'=>$newstockstock, 'purchased'=> $newstockpurchased, 
'low'=>$newstocklow, 'date'=> $newstockdate, 'picture'=> $newstockpicture);
```

Comment: Hi It is still appearing errors

Comment: You have forgot to add price, stock and low parameters in your $dbParams array

Comment: I have updated the answer to cover the error at line 16

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'game' cannot be null' in N:\ftp\compc\ac12mm\Practical 2 Files\addContact.php:17 Stack trace: #0 N:\ftp\compc\ac12mm\Practical 2 Files\addContact.php(17): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in N:\ftp\compc\ac12mm\Practical 2 Files\addContact.php on line 17

Comment: That means in your database you have marked 'game' column as not null while null is being passed through your query

Comment: Also be careful in your query because when you pass values without specifying statements like insert into x values('hii') instead of insert into x(`name`) values('hii'). You need to pass values for all the columns in your  database table and in exact order as they exist there.

Comment: I suggest you to read some PHP books and get more clear understanding of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic error in your code:

```
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("insert into stock values (null, :game, :console,
:age, :genre, :price, :status, :purchased, :low, :date, :picture,)";
```

Take a look at the end, you need to fix your line, somehing like that will work way better:

```
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("insert into stock values (null, :game, :console,
:age, :genre, :price, :status, :purchased, :low, :date, :picture)");
```

Removing the "," after "picture" and adding ")" to close your statement will make a valid php line.

**EDIT:** You also forget to add params for ":price", ":stock" and ":low" on line 16, so your query will probably fail if you don't set those variable.